# Chop down chained method calls in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, code-formatting

I use `Android Studio 2.2.2`. I have a code like this:

```
new StringBuilder ( ).append ( "<script type='text/x-mathjax-config'>" ).append ( "MathJax.Hub.Config({ " ).append ( "showMathMenu: false, " ).append ( "jax: ['input/TeX','output/HTML-CSS'], " ).append ( "extensions: ['tex2jax.js','toMathML.js'], " ).append ( "TeX: { extensions: ['AMSmath.js','AMSsymbols.js'," ).append ( "'noErrors.js','noUndefined.js'] }, " ).append ( "});</script>" ).append ( "<script type='text/javascript' " ).append ( "src='file:///android_asset/MathJax/MathJax.js'" ).append ( "></script>" ).append ( "<span id='math'></span><pre><span id='mmlout'></span></pre>" ).toString ( )
```

As you can see, it is very long and represented in one line. Is there a way to convert it to this:

```
new StringBuilder ( )
.append ( "<script type='text/x-mathjax-config'>" )
.append ( "MathJax.Hub.Config({ " )
.append ( "showMathMenu: false, " )
.append ( "jax: ['input/TeX','output/HTML-CSS'], " )
.append ( "extensions: ['tex2jax.js','toMathML.js'], " )
.append ( "TeX: { extensions: ['AMSmath.js','AMSsymbols.js'," )
.append ( "'noErrors.js','noUndefined.js'] }, " )
.append ( "});</script>" )
.append ( "<script type='text/javascript' " )
.append ( "src='file:///android_asset/MathJax/MathJax.js'" )
.append ( "></script>" )
.append ( "<span id='math'></span><pre><span id='mmlout'></span></pre>" )
.toString ( )
```

In above each line starts with `.append()` and includes only one of them. This is more readable.

Note:

1. Above code is an example, so performance is not importatnt here.
2. I know I can go `Settings > Editor > General` and select `Use soft wrap in editor` and `Use original line's indent for wrapped parts` , but that results some thing like this, which is not readable:

[image]

Comment: You could not use a StringBuilder and instead use Freemarker or something for HTML templates

Comment: @cricket_007 It seems that you propose `template engines`. But I want to find a way in `Android Studio` (for example `code reformatting`) to do that for me.

Comment: Editor - Code style - Java - Chained method calls. Select "chop down if long" and "Align when multiline". Or use kotlin and it multi-line strings :-) But you shouldn't use a StringBuilder in the first place here. Just use `+` to concatenate the various parts of the string. Bonus: the concatenation will happen at compile-time rather than runtime.

Comment: I understand what you want, I just don't see the need for it. There's also other libraries specifically for MathJax

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you for your reply. Please add your comment as answer, so I can mark it as accepted answer and may help others.

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you for your reply! Above codes are for example. But I'm interesting for libraries in about running `MathJax` on `Android`, specially if their size with assets  are small. Can you reference to some of them?

Comment: Is size really that important? https://github.com/kexanie/MathView

Comment: @cricket_007 OK! Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editor - Code style - Java - Chained method calls. Select "chop down if long" and "Align when multiline". Or use kotlin and it multi-line strings :-)

But you shouldn't use a `StringBuilder` in the first place here. Just use `+` to concatenate the various parts of the string. Bonus: the concatenation will happen at compile-time rather than runtime.